# Which version of FindBugs can run on Java 1.4?

Tags: java, findbugs

I want to run FindBugs on a project, but we're still stuck with Java 1.4 (and I won't go political now... :-}). The latest version of FindBugs can only run on JRE 1.5+, so I'm wondering which version was the last to support 1.4?

*Update* FindBugs v1.2.1 is running on Java 1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you run FindBugs on a Java 6 JRE against your legacy project?

Comment: You don't even need a Java 6 JRE. You only need to Java 5 or better. 6 would probably be best to take advantage of some of the optimizations they've made, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @cringe: +1 to Ricky Clarkson's answer.  I've got about ten different VMs running on this system. Just use the one you need to run the software you want.  For example I've got a 1.6 VM to run IntelliJ IDEA and create only 1.5 *.jars*.

Comment: Does FindBugs inspect the JRE to discover potential problems or are all rules enclosed in the FindBugs binary itself?

Comment: I thought about running FindBugs on a newer JRE against my project but I'd like to have it included in the build process. Unfortunatly the 1.4 is burried deep in the chained ant scripts, and I can't touch that yet. It's on my roadmap though...

Comment: There is a mess of project configuration right now, because the backend already uses 1.5, but the frontend has to be on 1.4 because the application server is that old, and having it updated... well, let's say, it's not in my hands. %-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you can't run the latest version of FindBugs on Java 1.4 code as long as you have the 1.5 JRE. There might be some warnings and errors that you have to turn off, since they don't apply to 1.4, such as any relating to Generics (which were introduced in 5). But I honestly don't see why you can't run FindBugs on old Java code.